# regex to filter files using filename shell script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sftp

Trying to filter files based on filename convention

```
eg: Standard_<number>_<15digitnumber>.xml
```

I was able to use the below command to get the files that matches above criteria but it also includes varchar in the middle.

```
ls Standard_[0-9]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml
```

**Output**:
Standard_2149190256_151116162725717.xml
Standard_2149190257_151116162725717.xml
Standard_**2149ABCDE**_151116162725717.xml

In above highlighted output it returns string as i have * following the number in middle. I tried placing + before and after  [0-9] to include only numbers but the command is not working.

```
ls Standard_[0-9]+_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml
```

**Output**: Can't ls: "/somefolder/Standard_[0-9]+_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" not found

```
ls Standard_+[0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml
```

**Output**: Can't ls: "/somefolder/Standard_+[0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" not found

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page to help you properly format this question so that it's legible

Comment: @ctwheels thank you for your response. I just updated the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Bash's [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) can help you here:

```
$ printf "%s\n" Standard*
Standard_2149190256_151116162725717.xml
Standard_2149190257_151116162725717.xml
Standard_2149ABCDE_151116162725717.xml

$ shopt -s extglob nullglob

$ printf "%s\n" Standard_+([0-9])_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xml
Standard_2149190256_151116162725717.xml
Standard_2149190257_151116162725717.xml
```

Here, `+([0-9])` matches a sequence of one or more digits, and we exclude the file "Standard_2149ABCDE_151116162725717.xml".

Answer (score 0):

Bash don't have regex, shell have [Globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

You will use regex in linux in commands like, egrep, sed ...

file Standard_01234_012345678912345.xml

1 - as you are doing

```
 ls Standard_[0-9]+_[0-9]{15}.xml
 ls: cannot access Standard_[0-9]+_[0-9]{15}.xml: No such file or directory
```

2 - Using egrep

```
ls -l |egrep Standard_[0-9]+_[0-9]{15}.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   0 Oct 24 16:07 Standard_01234_012345678912345.xml
```

As you can see, you regex is not the problem, but where you are using. You can learn about globbing or use egrep, sed, awk instead of simple ls.

Tip 1: [0-9]{15} is the same thing as repeate [0-9] 15 times.

Tip 2:  Standard_[0-9]* works in part because **'*'**  is wildcard in regex and globbing

Answer (score 0):

The problem with 'ls' is that it isn't completely regex posix compliant.  That way lies madness.  However 'grep' IS compliant and plays nicely with 'ls'.

```
    ls Standard_*.xml | grep -P [[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]{15}
```

I like the "perl" style regexp (PCRE)  so that explains the weird-looking '-P' on the 'grep' command.

Comment: i tried to use the command you provided and the result is all the files that starts with Standard also i  missed to mention that i want to execute this after connecting to SFTP server.  below is the command i am using to connect to SFTP before running the ls command.ideally i have to use Mget to get all the files matching the file convention.                                                                           
                                                                                                               
         sftp  -oIdentityFile=/<Home>/.ssh/id_rsa  <user>@<server>